# How to test for group differences in poisson distributed variables with unequal length?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, mathematical-statistics, poisson-distribution

I would like to test group differences in poisson distributed variables. However, I'm struggle to find appropriate approach(using `R`), which encounters unequal length of the variables in question and returns p values as well:

Here some data:

```
set.seed(2014)
a<- rnorm(1000, mean = 5, sd = 2)
b<- rnorm(1000, mean = 4, sd = 2)
c<- rnorm(1000, mean = 2, sd = 2)
# First vector
var1<-rpois(100000, exp(3+ 0.5*a - 0.25*b+0.3*c))
# Second vector
var2<-rpois(1000, exp(3+ 0.5*a - 0.5*b+0.6*c))
# Plotting distribution of var1
hist(var1)
```

[image]

```
# Plotting distribution of var2
hist(var2)
```

[image]

What I found was poisson.exact test from the `library(stats)`

```
poisson.test(var1,var2)
#Error in poisson.test(var1, var2) : 'x' and 'T' have incompatible length
```

Which however seems to use equal vectors.

Answer (score 1):

Your variables are conditionally Poisson, but the vector of variates (like var1) is a mixture of Poissons with different parameters.

The function `poisson.test` is not for comparing vectors that are different length mixtures of Poissons with different parameters.

If - as in your example - you have each poisson parameter appearing a fixed number of times in each vector (once in the second vector, 100 times in the first), then you can compare the *sum* of the poisson parameters, by summing var1 and var2 (which will then be Poisson with parameters equal to the sum of the parameters supplied to the `rpois` call, and then $T$ could contain `c(100,1)`).

Comment: Hi @Glen_b thank you for your answer. I'm sorry for confusing the `libraries`.  I edited the question. I'm not fully understand your answer, particularly '(once in the second vector, 100 times in the first)'. It was not my intension to use poisson parameter appearing a fixed number of times. I just wanted to reproduce somehow my real data visually in order to show the distribution.

Comment: If your real data look like your plots, the data does not come from a Poisson distribution. Your variable var2 contains 1000 draws where each one is from a *different* Poisson distribution.

Comment: Ah ok. What information would one need from the original data in order to properly describe the issue at hand and complement the example, given that the original data has the same shape as depicted?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm confused as well. Sorry for that. But according to your answer, the `code` have shown doesnt depict a Poission distribution rather depicts samples drawn from different Poission distributions. However, visually the plot resembles my original data. I still would like to test group differences given that the vectors a different. So I just assume that I cant do that by applying your answer. Therefore I thought to provide more information in order to be able test the differences in means.